# Create sparse matrix from tweets

Tags: r, twitter, sparse-matrix, sentiment-analysis

I have some tweets and other variables that I would like to convert into a sparse matrix.

This is basically what my data looks like. Right now it is saved in a data.table with one column that contains the tweet and one column that contains the score.

```
Tweet               Score
Sample Tweet :)        1
Different Tweet        0
```

I would like to convert this into a matrix that looks like this:

```
Score Sample Tweet Different :)
    1      1     1         0  1
    0      0     1         1  0
```

Where there is one row in the sparse matrix for each row in my data.table. Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to what you want

```
library(Matrix)
words = unique(unlist(strsplit(dt[, Tweet], ' ')))

M = Matrix(0, nrow = NROW(dt), ncol = length(words))
colnames(M) = words

for(j in 1:length(words)){
  M[, j] = grepl(paste0('\\b', words[j], '\\b'), dt[, Tweet])
}

M = cbind(M, as.matrix(dt[, setdiff(names(dt),'Tweet'), with=F]))

#2 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#     Sample Tweet :) Different Score
#[1,]      1     1  .         .     1
#[2,]      .     1  .         1     .
```

The only small issue is that the regex is not recognising `':)'` as a word. Maybe someone who knows regex better can advise how to fix this.

Comment: BTW I use data.table syntax in the above. Make sure you convert to data,table to use code as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I'm looking at this right can we just change grepl(paste0('\\b', words[j], '\\b'), dt[, Tweet]) to grepl(words[j], tweet$Tweet). It works in the test scenario, but I'm not sure if there's another scenario that I'm not thinking of where it would fail. Also, what happens if this was changed around a little bit and I wanted the frequency of the word occurrence in the sparse matrix. So if Different was written twice the sparse matrix would show a 2. Is there an easy way for that as well?

Comment: you can't just delete the `\\b`or it will match words which formpart of another word.  e.g. 'hat' will match 'that'

Comment: So I've done some digging. `paste0('(\\s|^)', words[j],'(\\s|$)')` is what I could find. The word has to either start at the beginning of a string, start with a space, or end with a space or end at the end of the line. I think that will give me the results I want, unless I'm overlooking something again.

Comment: Do you know if it would be easy to find the frequency of a word within a tweet for the sparse  matrix entry? Or is that a lot more difficult to program?

Comment: sure, it would be easy to do with a for loop and the table function, it's just not as easy to write it in vector format. I'll give it a shot though. Thanks again for the help.